# Способ проксирования сайтов через один сервер

Tags: nginx, proxy

У каждого сайта есть полноценный, собственный сервер(nginx+php-fpm, условно). 
Задача, как можно проще(Nginx/HAProxy или что-то подобное) проксировать сайты через один сервер c одним IP. 
Обязательное условие: SSL сертификат установлен только на сервере конкретного сайта и в целом в работу сайта не вмешиваемся, а просто проксируем.

"Набросал" схему, для понимания задачи.

[image]

С помощью чего можно реализовать подобное?

Comment: Единственный способ узнать, в какой сайт стучится клиент — посмотреть SNI, если он не зашифрован.

Comment: А ключ на расшифровку sni может быть отличный от ключа хттпс - то есть вообще без проблем, но с реализовали ли шифрованный сни в прокси?

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html